# Maven cannot resolve Jacob dependency using eclipse

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I have many maven dependencies in my maven springboot project but the jacob 1.10 dependency is not getting resolved.

I have to manually add the jacob.jar file at C:\Users\username.m2\repository\com\jacob\jacob\1.10. All other dependencies are getting resolved whenever a new dependency is added to the pom.xml.
This is not a duplicate question because I have already tried update project, force update of snapshot/releases or clean and build the project.

I have confirmed here "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jacob/jacob/1.10"
that the dependency info is correct.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jacob/jacob -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jacob</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacob</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>
```

and the marker says

```
The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\com\jacob\jacob\1.10\jacob-1.10.jar'
```

This red wiggly says

```
"Missing artifact com.jacob:jacob:jar:1.10".
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: The artifact does not exist in Maven Central https://search.maven.org/search?q=com.jacob

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This dependency is located in the JBoss Third Party Repository: https://mvnrepository.com/repos/jboss-thirdparty-releases

To resolve this just add to your list of repositories in your pom.xml:

```
<repository>
    <id>jboss-maven2-release-repository</id>
    <name>JBoss 3rd-party Repository</name>
    <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases/</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. I dont know how I missed that. By the way, I still wasn't able to resolve the dependency until I removed the <snapshots> and <releases> code segment that you suggested.

Comment: @NitinNanda apologies, that was a copy/paste error on my behalf, I've edited my answer

Comment: Thanks @Joshua Cross